# Prove that $I^2=2I$ as ideals in $Z[\sqrt { −3}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Let $I$ be the ideal generated by $2$ and $1+ \sqrt {−3}$ in the ring $Z[\sqrt { −3}]$.

Prove That $I^2=2I$.

We
have
$2I=2(2,1+ \sqrt {−3} )=(4,2+2 \sqrt −3 )$
$I^2=(2,1+ \sqrt {−3} )(2,1+ \sqrt {−3} )=(4,2+2 \sqrt {−3}, -2+2 \sqrt{−3} )$

Now I am convinced that if we have 3 ideals $(a),(b),(c)$ then $(a,b,a-b)=(a,b)$ because $(a-b)\subset (a,b)$.

Which gives $I^2= (4,2+2 \sqrt {−3})=2I$.

Is that all correct?
Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: I didn’t check your arithmetic but that looks exactly right!

Comment: I think that's absolutely right.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Interesting that $I\supsetneq (2)$ and yet $I\cdot I = (2)\cdot I$. Could not happen in a ring of integers, like $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}]$

Comment: Right, $\Bbb Z[\sqrt { −3}]$ is not a UFD that's why we have $I\ne (2)$ and yet $I^2=2I$. Is $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}]$ PID or UFD?